# Finding basis of vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $$A=\left\{A\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}\mid A^t=A \right\}$$ be the set of real symmetric $3\times 3$-matrices and let $$B=\left\{B\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}\mid t^B=B^t\right\},$$ here $t^B$ is the transpose of $B$ w.r.t. the antidiagonal.

1.) Prove that $A$ and $B$ are subspaces.

2.)Find the bases for vector subspaces $A$,$B$,$A\cap B$, $A+B$.

For 1. I think I should just check if: $αA_1 + βA_2$ is still in $A$ (similarly for $B$). But I am unsure how to do the second part. I am asking the question for the first time, so I hope I wrote the problem correctly. I thank you for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) requires from you to simply follow definition. I use the one given in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace), you should use the one provided in your lectures/textbook (there exist slightly different ways of defining the same entity). For $A$, checking whether $A$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ (over field $\mathbb{R}$):
0. $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$. Obviously true, check.
1. Zero vector $0$ is in $A$. Zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ is zero matrix, zero matrix is symmetric. Check.
2. $u, v \in A \implies u+v = w \in A$. Sum of symmetric matrices is symmetric (you can write rigorous proof). Check.
3. $u \in A, c \in \mathbb{R} \implies cu \in A$. Symmetric matrix multiplied by a scalar is still symmetric. Check.
Note that there may be shortcuts (in particular, you're right when saying that proving $A_1, A_2 \in A, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R} \implies \alpha A_1+\beta A_2 \in A$ is sufficient), but unless you've grown really confident in the subject or a shortcut saves significant effort, I wouldn't recommend to use them.

2) requires you to find a *basis* in a certain subspace. Once again, start from definition, I'm using [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)). First condition (non-existence of nontrivial linear combination equal to zero) is clearly equivalent to "any vector of basis can't be expressed as a linear combination of others" (why?). For example, set of nine matrices with one element $1$ and all other $0$ in each - 
$$\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0}, \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0}, ..., \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}$$
 would give you a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$.
Bad news: there is no universal way to find a basis for a vector space, you always have to make some sort of guess. Taking $B$ as an example, I need $$\pmatrix {x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & x_{1,3} \\ x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & x_{2,3} \\ x_{3,1} & x_{3,2} & x_{3,3} } : \pmatrix {x_{1,1} & x_{2,1} & x_{3,1} \\ x_{1,2} & x_{2,2} & x_{3,2} \\ x_{1,3} & x_{2,3} & x_{3,3} } = \pmatrix {x_{3,3} & x_{2,3} & x_{1,3} \\ x_{3,2} & x_{2,2} & x_{1,2} \\ x_{3,1} & x_{2,1} & x_{1,1} }$$
This gives me four non-trivial equalities ($x_{1,1} = x_{3,3}, x_{2,1}=x_{2,3}, x_{3,1} = x_{1,3}, x_{1,2} = x_{3,2}$) and any matrix satisfying them is in $B$. In other words, I get to define five matrix elements (say, $x_{1,1} = \alpha, x_{2,1} = \beta, x_{3,1} = \gamma, x_{1,2} = \delta, x_{2,2} = \epsilon$) however I want and others can be derived. Or, rephrasing again, $$b \in B \iff b = \alpha \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1} + \beta \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0} + ... + \epsilon \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0}$$
These five matrices (write down the missing two) seem like a basis. Double-checking: they can't give a non-trivial zero linear combination (each has $1$ in a position where others have $0$) and any element of $B$ can be produced as their linear combination. Done.

Comment: Thank you very much!  
Using this I get 6 matrixes in basis A, 5 matrixes in basis B(like you wrote). 2 matrixes in basis A and basis B are the same, therefore I conclude that basis A∩B is 2. Than I used formula dim(A+B) = dim(A) + dim(B) - dim(A∩B). So I get dim(A+B) = 5 + 6 -2 = 9. So I expect there are 9 matrixes in A+B.

Comment: If some elements in bases are not the same, it doesn't mean you can just throw them away. Case in point, $\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0} \in A \cap B$.

Answer (score 0):

In 2. you got to create a Basis. This means, that you get a set of elements of that subspace, whose linear combinations can create all elements of the subspace, bot not a single element, that is not in the subspace.

This is most easily done, by writing a generic $3 \times 3$ matrix done and identify, which elements have what relation to reduce the numbers of degrees of freedom. 
Example: Given the symmetric $3\times 3$, we know, that $x_{2,1}$ must be equal to $x_{1,2}$, so we can elimnate one of these from the basis.

In a more formal (and algorithmic) manner you could use any basis you find and use orthogonlization-shemes (like Gram-Schmidt or similar).

The question is also not clearly written, since there are infinite bases. It might want to ask for the simplest orthogonal basis, but that is not specific.

Comment: Why do you talk about orthogonalization? This wasn't asked for and cannot be done here anyway (without defining scalar product operation statement "$a$ is orthogonal to $b$" has no meaning).

Comment: If I understand this, than multiple basis are possible, but I just need to find 1 basis for each subspace, so it might be best to find a simple one.

Comment: Correct. You only need one. But it asks for "the" basis, as if there is only one. But simple bases are quite easy to find in these cases.